# How do I manipulate strings with regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm fairly new to java and I'm trying to get a part of a string:

Say I have a URL and I want a specific part of it, such as a filename:

```
String url = "http://example.com/filename02563.zip";
```

The 02563 will be generated at random every time and it's now always 5 characters long.
I want to have java find what's between "m/" (from .com/) to the end of the line to get the filename alone.

Now consider this example:

Say I have an html file that I want a snippet extracted from. Below would be the extracted example:

```
<applet name=someApplet id=game width="100%" height="100%" archive=someJarFile0456799.jar  code=classInsideAJarFile.class mayscript>
```

I want to extract the jar filename, so I want to get the text between "ve=" and ".jar". The extension will always be ".jar", so including this is not important.

How would I do this? If possible, could you comment the code so I understand what's happening?

Comment: What have you tried? We won't write the code *for* you, but we'll help you improve your own code...

Comment: For your example, you should use an XML parser.

Comment: You shouldn't use an XML parser on HTML, that way lies madness

Answer (score 3):

Use the Java [`URI` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) where you can access the individual elements.

```
URI uri = new URI("http://example.com/filename02563.zip");
String filename = uri.getPath();
```

Granted, this will need a little more work if the resource no longer resides in the root path.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `lastIndexOf()` and `substring()` methods from the String class to extract a specific piece of a String:

```
String url      = "http://example.com/filename02563.zip";
String filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1); //+1 skips ahead of the '/'
```

Comment: Also consider using the \z constant referencing to the end of input. A pattern might then look like "/(.+)\z" (untested).

Answer (score 0):

You have answers for your first question so this is for second one. Normally I would use some XML parser but your example is not valid XML file so this will be solved with regex (as you wanted).

```
String url = "<applet name=someApplet id=game width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" archive=someJarFile0456799.jar  code=classInsideAJarFile.class mayscript>";

Pattern pattern= Pattern.compile("(?<=archive=).*?(?= )");
Matcher m=pattern.matcher(url);
if(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

output:

```
someJarFile0456799.jar
```